# How do I draw an icon in a Windows dialog box?

Tags: windows, gdi

I am trying to draw an icon in the title bar of a Windows dialog box. I am not trying to replace the normal icon for the dialog. I am trying to draw an icon in addition to the minimize, maximize/restore and close icons. To that effect, I am sending the WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX message so I can calculate my position. Try as I might, I can't get the icon in my image list to draw. I have been able to draw the icon in the client area. I finally just tried drawing at (0,0) and at (100,0) and now in the middle of the title bar. I just never see the icon in the title bar. I also added code to draw below the title bar just to make sure my icon is fine and the icon draws in the window.

First I override OnNcPaint, call the base class and then my routine to draw my icon.

void MyDialog::OnNcPaint()
{

```
CDialog::OnNcPaint();

CWindowDC dc(this);

DrawNonClientArea( &dc );
```

}

void MyDialog::DrawAttachIcon(CDC* pDC)
{

```
if( -1 != m_AttachIconIndex && pDC )
{
    TITLEBARINFOEX TitleBarInfoEx;
    TitleBarInfoEx.cbSize = sizeof( TitleBarInfoEx );

    ::SendMessage( GetSafeHwnd(), WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX, 0, (LPARAM)&TitleBarInfoEx );

    // As per the MSDN, rectangle indexes are 0 (reserved), 1 (reserved), 2 - minimize button, 3 - maximize button, 4 - help button and 5 close button.
    CSize sizeClose( TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].right - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].left, TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].bottom - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].top );
    CSize sizeMaximize( TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[3].right - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[3].left, TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[3].bottom - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[3].top );
    CSize sizeMinimize( TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].right - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].left, TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].bottom - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].top );

    int padding_x = TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].left - TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[3].right;
    int padding_y = TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[5].top - TitleBarInfoEx.rcTitleBar.top;

    CPoint pt;

    pt.x = TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].left - sizeMinimize.cx;
    pt.y = TitleBarInfoEx.rgrect[2].top;

    // I give up. Try to draw in the middle of the caption.
    pt.x = (TitleBarInfoEx.rcTitleBar.right - TitleBarInfoEx.rcTitleBar.left)/2; pt.y = 0;

    m_ilIconAttachToFrame.Draw( pDC, m_AttachIconIndex, pt, ILD_NORMAL );
    pt.y += 200;
    m_ilIconAttachToFrame.Draw( pDC, m_AttachIconIndex, pt, ILD_NORMAL );
}
```

}

That last two lines was to just draw in the window and the icon draws where I expect. I also blasted a filled rect first on the icons (close, minimize ...), then the whole title area using the rect from the title bar info. And even blasted a rect over the entire window, which resulted in only the client area being painted with the color. Is there an exclusion rect over the caption? I called GetClipRgn and the return value was zero, so I don't think there is.

Comment: Pay close attention to your coordinate spaces. TITLEBARINFOEX uses screen coordinates, but the window DC is in window coordinates.

Comment: Hi Raymond, I have added a call to ScreenToClient. Same results. Also, in my testing I just gave up and set pt.x = 0; pt.y = 0; Then I set pt.x to be 100. I also moved my window to my  main monitor and positioned it at (0,0) to see what would happen. Even with my change, the only drawing I am getting is when I add 200 to pt. y. Then, it draws with centered in width and at y = 200. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Perhaps some progress. I removed the call to CDialog::OnNcPaint. My window rendered with a different frame. It used the standard child frame instead of a popup frame. But, as I resized my window, I see my bitmap both in the title bar and below in the client area due to my extra call to display again with y = 200. I guess that if I implement OnNcPaint, I am not supposed to call the base CDialog code and instead I have to render everything myself. Not at all what I was hoping for. I just want to draw my image. I'm going to see if I can draw, create an exclude region and then call the base code.

Comment: Gee. I found some of my own very old code that has a comment that said do not call the base MFC code. Looks like I have to implement the entire NC drawing. Rats.